# Thoughtbot's Clearance gem, overriding url_after_destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, clearance

I was able to successfully override `url_after_create`, but my `url_after_destroy` is being ignored.

What am I messing up?

routes:

```
  map.resource  :session,
    :controller => 'sessions',
    :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]
```

my Sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < Clearance::SessionsController
  private
    def url_after_create
      puts "************after create****************"  #called on sign in
    end

  def url_after_destroy
    puts "************after destroy****************"  #never called
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs say:

> You may also need to add code such as
>   the following to your routes.rb:

```
 map.sign_out 'sign_out',
     :controller => 'sessions',
     :action     => 'destroy',
     :method     => :delete
```

That's what I'm missing.  Perhaps 'may' is not the best choice of verb for documentation.

Comment: Updated the docs (it's a wiki!): https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/wiki/Usage

Comment: And people say that you can't get support with open source projects.  Wow Dan, thank you.